# Retrieve long from a version string

Tags: java

I have a list of current application version:
[
    null,
    "0.2.1-RELEASE",
    "0.2.2-RELEASE",
    "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "0.4.1-RELEASE",
    "0.4.2-RELEASE"
]

They are string in the DB.

I want to use Java match RegExp to retrieve long from those string
like 0.2 from 0.2.1-RELEASE
0.4 from "0.4.1-RELEASE" and "0.4.2-RELEASE"

Anybody know how?

Comment: `0.2` isn't a long. Do you mean `double`?

Comment: pretty much the easiest extraction regex you could write, I'd really recommend you just go learn how to write regexes.

Comment: @AndyTurner It's not really a floating-point either. It's *really* a Maven version, for which the parser is available.

Comment: Take a look at [jsemver](https://github.com/zafarkhaja/jsemver) or something similar.

Comment: double is fine, as long as it's a number I can do greater or less condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - It's not a Long - You can extract it as a string and parse it to a **Double**;

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(("(\\d\\.\\d)"));
    Matcher m = p.matcher("0.1.0.2 RELEASE");
    if (m.find()){
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(m.group(0)));
    }
```

PS: Check http://regexr.com/3d9uj to practice regular expressions

Comment: Thanks, But if the version String is "12.12.00", the code return 2.1, I expect 12.12. :)

Comment: Whooops - my bad: pattern should be: \\d+\\.\\d+   (notice that only first part of version number is matched - and version 1.12 will be treated as lower than 1.2 - which is wrong - consider another data structure than double to compare version numbering)